# Social Icons in Center when in Mobile and to Right when in Desktop

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap, icons

I am trying to Organise my Social Icons so that when the site is in Mobile the icons are in the center of the Div. When the site is in Desktop, the icons should be in the right of the Div.

**My Problem:** Currently the icons are just aligning to left and then in center in mobile. I cant get it to align to right instead of left.

HTML Code:

```
    <div class="soimg">
        <div class="images">
            <img src="social/facebook.png"/>
            <img src="social/insta.png"/>
            <img src="social/twitter.png"/>
            <img src="social/youtube.png"/>
        </div>
    </div>



CSS: 


    .soimg img {
        height:30px;
        width: auto;
        margin-right: 5px;
        display: inline-block;
        filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale"); /* Firefox 3.5+ */
filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
        opacity: 0.4;

        text-align: right;
    }

    .soimg img:hover {
        filter: none;
        -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
        opacity: 1;
    }

    .images {
        height:50px;
        background-color:#1c1c1c;
        margin-top: -20px;
        margin-bottom: -20px;
    }  
    @media screen and (max-width:700px) {
        .soimg {
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            text-align: center;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's the problem you are having?

Comment: @KevinBoucher Currently it only aligns to the left and then moves to center in mobile - i want right rather than left

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to specify the `text-align:right`. It is not the default value.

```
.soimg {
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't do what i want - it positions it permanently to the right

Comment: Not if you place your media query after that assignment and override it.

Comment: @RandomMath is correct.  [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/8g56wbah/) is a jsfiddle which shows the styles in action.  Change the size of the frame to see the text-align change.